# Comparing today's date with another date in moment is returning the wrong date, why?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) 1.7.0 to try and compare today's date with another date but the `diff` function is saying they are 1 day apart for some reason.

**code**:

```
var releaseDate = moment("2012-09-25");
var now = moment(); //Today is 2012-09-25, same as releaseDate  
console.log("RELEASE: " + releaseDate.format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
console.log("NOW: " + now.format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
console.log("DIFF: " + now.diff(releaseDate, 'days'));
```

**console**:

```
RELEASE: 2012-09-25
NOW: 2012-09-25
DIFF: 1
```

Ideas?

Comment: i have 1.7.0, i tested your code and i got `DIFF: 0` - are you sure nothing was changed in your moment.js?

Comment: I think it's something to do with timezones or utc/local.  If I log the `.hours()` of `releaseDate` and `now` it yields different results for me.  If I use `var now = moment().sod()` [(docs)](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/sod/) it currently works as expected, but I'm not sure how much I trust that.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) (and brief testing), moment.js creates wrappers around date objects. The statement:

```
var now = moment();
```

creates a "moment" object that at its heart has a new Date object created as if by `new Date()`, so hours, minutes and seconds will be set to the current time.

The statement:

```
var releaseDate = moment("2012-09-25");
```

creates a moment object that at its heart has a new Date object created as if by `new Date(2012, 8, 25)` where the hours, minutes and seconds will all be set to zero for the local time zone.

`moment.diff` returns a value based on a the **rounded** difference in ms between the two dates. To see the full value, pass `true` as the third parameter:

```
 now.diff(releaseDate, 'days', true)
 ------------------------------^
```

So it will depend on the time of day when the code is run and the local time zone whether `now.diff(releaseDate, 'days')` is zero or one, even when run on the same local date.

If you want to compare just dates, then use:

```
var now = moment().startOf('day');
```

which will set the time to 00:00:00 in the local time zone.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! Using `moment().sod()` eliminates my rounding problem, as tested using the third parameter you mentioned.

Comment: Note that `sod` will only work up to version 2, when you will have to use `startOf('day')`.

Answer (score 3):

RobG's answer is correct for the question, so this answer is just for those searching how to compare dates in momentjs.

I attempted to use startOf('day') like mentioned above:

```
var compare = moment(dateA).startOf('day') === moment(dateB).startOf('day');
```

This did not work for me.

I had to use [isSame](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same/):

```
var compare = moment(dateA).isSame(dateB, 'day');
```