# moment.js "invalid date" calculating time difference

Tags: javascript, php, momentjs

I'm trying to calculate the time difference in hours & mins between 2 form fields, but I get "Invalid Date" returned. I've tried to use other examples and make them work to suit my needs. The input is  for both start and end fields.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/moment.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function calculate(){
                            var start = document.getElementById(StartTime);
                            var end = document.getElementById(EndTime);
                            var diff = moment.utc(moment(end,"HH:mm").diff(moment(start,"HH:mm"))).format("HH:mm")
                            document.form.total.value = diff;
                    }
</script>
<form method="POST" name="form" id="form" action="test2.php">
<?php
echo "time1: <input type='text'  name='StartTime' id='StartTime' onChange='calculate()'/> <br />";
echo "time2: <input type='text' name='EndTime' id='EndTime' onChange='calculate()' /> <br />";
echo "difference: <input type='text' name='total' id='total' /> <br /> ";
echo "<Br />";
?>
</form>
```

Thanks

Comment: `getElementById` takes a string, so it should be `var start = document.getElementById("StartTime");` and so on.. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById

Comment: Thanks @nha, that's fixed the "Invalid Date" problem, now I need to move on to the next issue of the difference showing "00:00"

Comment: What is your input for each date then ? And have you seen this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12593653/moment-js-diff-incorrect ?

Comment: StartTime = 09:00; EndTime = 10:30. So only time difference, no date input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at the following code :

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.4/moment.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function calculate(){
        var start = document.getElementById("startTime").value;
        var end = document.getElementById("endTime").value;
        var formatStr = "HH:mm";
        var diff = moment.utc(moment(end, formatStr).diff(moment(start, formatStr)));
        document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = diff.format(formatStr);
    }
</script>

<input type='text' id='startTime' onChange='calculate()'/>
<input type='text' id='endTime' onChange='calculate()' /> 
<div id='total' />
</html>
```

I removed the php code since it is not useful to debug this, and the issue is unrelated.
Note that you need to get the input value with `.value`.